# IE8 css3 border radius with x and y attributes

Tags: internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, css, css3pie

Does anyone know of a way to do the following in IE8?

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 70% 100%;
```

CSS3PIE only supports the simple border radius it seems, as well as most of the other IE css3 plug-ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIE does in fact support different x/y radii per corner; however you have to do it using the shorthand syntax, as described in the documentation: http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/#border-radius

For your example, it would be:

```
border-radius: 0 0 0 70% / 0 0 0 100%;
```

As far as I'm aware, PIE is the only one of the IE CSS3 polyfills that supports this in any fashion.

Comment: Thanks Lojjic, i had already converted the layout to images but i will give this a try.